# How to add additional source code to an imported existing makefile-project with eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, import, makefile, project

I have an existing makefile c-Project. I prebuilt it in my shell with `make` and `make install` as it was described in the ReadMe-file.
Then I imported it as File->Import "Existing code as Makefile Project". Again I pressed the "Build"-button but I think, as it was built before out of the shell it has not been built again.

Console says:

```
09:14:15 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project candis ****
make all 
echo "Make each directory individually."
Make each directory individually.
echo "``make lib'' makes the libraries"
make lib'' makes the libraries
echo "``make clean'' cleans out binaries and .o files everywhere"
make clean'' cleans out binaries and .o files everywhere
echo "``make tar'' tars up a distribution and redoes the libs"
make tar'' tars up a distribution and redoes the libs

09:14:15 Build Finished (took 136ms)
```

Then I tried to create a new Source Code File, I named it "prog1.c". I saved it and I pressed again the "Build"-Button but I think nothing happened so my Program.

How can I create a working function?
I might change something in my Makefile maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You have to adapt the makefile, otherwise the "prog1.c" file is not compiled.

The reason is that the compiler doesn't know what you want to compile, unless you tell him. That is what makefiles do.

What kind of makefiles do you have? I might maybe help you, if I can.

Comment: I tried to answer my own question, but this is not possible for me so far (too less reputatuion). May I send you an e-mail and you can post this here?